# Razor - Hidden field value stays the same after submitting

Tags: c#, razor

I'm trying to get a number of forms, each with a hidden field and drop down.

```
<table class="table">
@foreach (var sport in Model.Sports)
{        
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index"))
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.Label(sport.Name, sport.Name)
                @Html.Hidden("sportId", sport.Id)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DropDownList("masterSelect", new SelectList((IEnumerable<ThingModel>)Model.Things, "Id", "Name", Model.GetThing(sport.Id).Id), new { @class = "dropleft", onchange = "this.form.submit();" })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
}
</table>
```

The first time I load the page, and change the value in a drop down, the form posts the correct values to the controller. When the page reloads, the `sport.Name` fields are all different (as expected) but the hidden fields all have the same value, the one selected from the drop down. Even when I debugged the cshtml, I can see `sport.Id` has the correct value but its not the one being rendered.

Comment: Is Id a route parameter as well?

Comment: No, default routing